# Unable to map SharePoint Online site to file Explorer using "net use M: "https://******.sharepoint.com/sites/HR"" command

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, mapped-folder, file-explorer

We have SharePoint online tenant, and we want the users to access the document libraries files and folders using file explorer when they have internet connectivity. I tried running this command to map a document library as a mapped drive:-

```
%systemroot%\System32\conhost.exe powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -windowstyle hidden -command "(new-object -com internetexplorer.application).visible=$true"

@echo off

net use M: "https://******.sharepoint.com/sites/HR"

taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe
```

where it worked well for one user and failed for the others, where they get this error:-

[image: User's image]

Now we have disabled OneDrive inside our machines since it is consuming a lot of space, and instead we want the users to access the files and folders using file explorer when they have internet connection. so any advice about the error we are getting? although i added the SharePoint site to the trusted site insdie IE and we also those urls:-

https://*.sharepoint.com

https://*.microsoftonline.com

Comment: Check this: [SharePoint Online: View in File Explorer available in Microsoft Edge](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/09/22/sharepoint-online-view-in-file-explorer-available-in-microsoft-edge/). Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP thanks for the reply. but how i can map this as a network drive for the users,,, so they do not have to manully click " View in file explorer"?

Comment: Why wouldn't they just use the OneDrive for Business app and the Sync functionality?

Comment: @CallumCrowley as i mentioned on my question. Now we have disabled OneDrive inside our machines since it is consuming a lot of space, and instead we want the users to access the files and folders using file explorer when they have internet connection.

Comment: OneDrive will only consume space if people choose to keep the files offline on their machine. If they do open files, it may load on to their machine but they can always click the "Free up disk space" button to free space on their hard drive. It doesn't make sense to use the Open in File Explorer functionality over OneDrive.

Comment: @CallumCrowley you know the customers and their endless requirements, they need to have the same experience as for on Prem file share, they find OneDrive over complicated, they are people from none-IT depts. so let concentrate on my original issue, rather than discussing OneDrive over file share, where i agree with you that OneDrive will win.. but our customer have different view :(

Comment: I think they are out of luck really. This functionality is legacy and very difficult to implement now. They are better off using OneDrive and training their users, OneDrive provides an experience inside File Explorer, just like an on-prem file share.